# iOS returns that there are no twitter accounts on phone, eventhough there is one

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter

I check if there is used twitter account with this code:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
```

If i run it on iOS 6 simulator with `twitter` account, `arrayOfAccounts.count` is 1, but on iPhone 4 iOS6, `arrayOfAccounts.count` is 0.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: did you login succesfully in twitter account in setting on iphone 4

Comment: Yes i am logged in in simulator and on device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also got same problem. Use this code.

Reason for this is that it does not get permissions from settings for Twitter account access, so we need to check that first.

```
if ([TWRequest class])
            {
                ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
                ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:
                                              ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

                [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                                              completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
                 {
                     if (granted == YES)
                     {
                         // Get account and communicate with Twitter API
                         NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account
                                                     accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

                         if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
                         {
                             ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];
                         }
                  }
                     else
                     {
                         NSLog(@"No Twitter Access Error");
                         return;
                     }
                 }];
            }



            if ([TWRequest class])
            {
                ACAccountStore *as = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
                ACAccountType *accountType = [as accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
                NSArray *twitterAccounts = [as accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                if (!twitterAccounts.count)
                {
                    NSLog(@"No Twitter Account configured");

                    return;
                }
            }
}
```