# What can i do when login with "ACAccountStore" doesn't get granted?

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter, acaccount

I'm currently developing an app that uses ACAccountStore to access the twitter account to fetch tweets. Everything works good, but i've no clue what i can display or do if the user doesn't grant promise to the accounts.

My first thought was something about displaying a login view or switch to the iOS settings, but this isn't working in iOS 5.1 or above anymore? Does somebody have another better solution? :)

Best regards

EDIT: I'm not looking for the whole auth-code. Just for the case, where the user doesn't grant access to the account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *twitterType =  [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier: ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter]; 

// Request Access for Twitter Accounts
[store requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterType
  withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
   if(granted){
    // Handle Granted condition
} else{
    // We didn’t get access, output why not
    NSLog(@”%@”,[error localizedDescription]);
   }
}];
```

above is a sample authorization requested.

> You can get error description in the else part and it is a good idea
>   to show the error description to the user in the alert view or other
>   option is to ask user to allow access for the app through settings
>   app.

You cant switch to the settings app programatically.

Comment: Hi, thank's for the info, i already had that before. The problem is that i don't know what to display if i don't get access. Do you display a simple alert..?

Comment: This answer is using a DEPRECATED function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797409/ios-returns-that-there-are-no-twitter-accounts-on-phone-eventhough-there-is-one/13797575#13797575

Answer (score 2):

when the user doesn't grant you access, simply show an error saying "app was denied access to twitter" and then ignore it -> assume like you don't have twitter